# How to play 2 different songs on android phone to 2 bluetooth speakers, both playing 1 song each?

Tags: audio, android, bluetooth, speakers

so I work in retail, I'm trying to have music play over my store's bluetooth sound system, as well as, watch some TV on my bluetooth headphones when there are no customers. I'm looking for a way to play 2 lines of audio from my Samsung Z Fold 4 through bluetooth and have it split sources to each speaker

I have tried galaxys sound assistant and their built-in separate app sound settings (it does dual sound, both sources play to both outputs or it just wants to do the phone and 1 bt device) and I've searched online for an answer and yielded no results for what I want. If anyone knows a fix or if this kind of feature is even out yet, it would be appreciated!

Comment: There's no such feature.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately Bluetooth does not have enough bandwidth for multiple decent-quality audio streams.

Classically, Bluetooth has two main audio-transmitting schemes, called profiles.

The first one was the "headset profile" for those old one-ear Bluetooth cell phone headsets, which allowed two-way mono cellular telephone quality audio, which is okay for voice calls, but sucks for things like music and the audio from videos.

The later, higher quality profile was called "A2DP" and was one-way decent quality stereo audio, suitable for music and the audio from videos. Unfortunately, a single A2DP session uses all the bandwidth of traditional Bluetooth, so there's no way for you to do two A2DP sessions simultaneously.

Some later versions of Bluetooth had ways to get more bandwidth by borrowing use of the Wi-Fi chipset in both devices (if both devices also had Wi-Fi, especially in a combo Bluetooth/Wi-Fi wireless module), but I don't think it ever caught on in the marketplace. So still to this day, most Bluetooth connections only have enough bandwidth for a single A2DP session.